# How to make modal not close when error in input, Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap, twitter

I am doing an add client form(in modal view) I want to place an error message in the modal header. 
Yes, I am able to do that. The problem is, the modal will close and the message will be showed after
the user open it again.

How to make the modal stay open with the error displayed. Thank you. Newbie here.

Comment: maybe this helps: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11868599/how-to-get-twitter-bootstrap-modals-to-stay-open-on-form-submit)

Comment: And how do you expect us to help you without any line of code you already wrote? ;) We ain't magicians

Answer (score 1):

You detect the click event on the button when fired, then make your test, if the stuff is good, you let submit (don't cancel the event ) otherwise, you cancel the event and show the error. Here is an example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $( "#button" ).click(function( event ) {
            if (error){
                show error
                event.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }
            });
    });
```