# Showing error messages in another file

Tags: php, html

I'm sorry for newbie question but I really can't figure it out how to do this. So first I have contact form which is in modal window. The server side of the contact form (**PHP side**) is in another file `contact.php`. In this file I have some validation for the fields. What I want is when there is empty field or wrong input to show error message on the form. Right now is loading contact.php and the errors are there. 
This is the part for validation from `contact.php`

```
  function died($error) {
    echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
    echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />"; 
    echo $error."<br /><br />"; 
    echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
    die(); 
}
 // validation expected data exists 
if(!isset($_POST['firstname']) || 
    !isset($_POST['lastname']) ||
    !isset($_POST['email']) || 
    !isset($_POST['phone']) || 
    !isset($_POST['description'])) { 
    died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
} 
$firstname = $_POST['firstname']; // required 
$lastname = $_POST['lastname']; // required 
$email = $_POST['email']; // required 
$phone = $_POST['phone']; // not required 
$description = $_POST['description']; // required 
$error_message = ""; 
 $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/'; 
if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email)) { 
   $error_message .= 'The email address is not valid!<br />'; 
} 
$string_exp = "/^[a-zA-Z\p{Cyrillic}0-9\s\-]+$/u"; 
if(!preg_match($string_exp,$firstname)) {
   $error_message .= 'The name is not valid.<br />';
}
if(!preg_match($string_exp,$lastname)) { 
   $error_message .= 'The last name is not valid.<br />'; 
}
if(strlen($description) < 2) {
   $error_message .= 'The field for description is not valid.<br />'; 
} 
if(strlen($error_message) > 0) { 
   died($error_message);
} 
...
```

and the html form below

```
  <div class="send-icon" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#contact-form">
        <i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i>
    </div>
    <p class="light-text">Contact Us</p>

    <!-- Contact Form Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade contact-form" id="contact-form" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="contact-form" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                </button>
                <div class="modal-body">    
  <!-- *****  Contact form ***** -->
  <form class="form" name="contactform" action="contact/contact.php" method="post">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="form-group col-md-6">
       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstname" name="firstname" placeholder="firstname">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group col-md-6">
       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastname" name="lastname" placeholder="lastname">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group col-md-6">
       <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" >
   </div>
   <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" >
   </div>             
   <div class="form-group col-md-12 mab-none">
        <textarea rows="6" class="form-control" id="description" name="description" placeholder="description" ></textarea>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group col-md-12">
        <button class="button bold-text main-bg" type="submit" ><i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i></button>
   </div>
 </div>
</form>
```

So again excuse my question if is "too newbie" for you guys but I really need some help here.

Comment: If PHP file is called with javascript we need to see code of that javascript file.

Comment: No.. is just that. Form action is `action="contact/contact.php"`. No javascript.

Comment: You're best using Ajax for this. There are many scripts out there.

Comment: So add javascript validations, bad idea to call server every time when submitting a corrupted form.

Comment: I have tried with [JavaScript Form Validation](http://www.javascript-coder.com/html-form/javascript-form-validation.phtml) and is working good ... but is not good because user can stop this popup window whit error message.

Comment: Can you show your file structure? The HTML is on a file an `contact.php` has nothing to do with it, right?

Comment: It is not MVC. It's included in this `action=""`. It is onepage site(index.php) where is the contact form and second file `contact.php` which just send email taken from [this tutorial](http://www.freecontactform.com/email_form.php)

Comment: They are two files `index.php` with the HTML contact form and `contact.php` which send the email.

Comment: If you have an error, you should redirect to your HTML form (see [header()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)) and display the error message there. In order to keep the error message you should use the [session](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php).

Comment: You mean in `function dead($error)` instead of `die();` at the end to put redirect with session?

Comment: Or include your PHP form submission code before your HTML. It would execute only if the form has been submitted. (Better solution than the 1st I suggested I think.)

Comment: @Select Yes, 1st solution would be, instead of having a `die()`, save the error message in the session, then redirect to index.php . In index.php, if there is an error message in the session, display it and remove it from session. (I'll write an answer, that's better.)

Comment: This solution with the sessions didn't work in my case because the form is in modal windows. It is not visible on the page until user didn't click on the button to show it. It must stay open when is showing the error..

Comment: I have edited my question and added extra lines on the contact form how it is opened..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your code is quite the same as [this tutorial](http://www.freecontactform.com/email_form.php) (as you sayed in comments):

**What you have:**

So currently you have your form in `index.php`:

```
<!-- HTML stuff before -->

<form class="form" name="contactform" action="contact.php" method="post">
    <!-- Input tags -->
</form>

<!-- HTML stuff after -->
```

And the form is processed in `contact.php`:

```
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
     function died($error) {
         echo 'You have an error blahblah.';
         echo $error;
         die();
     }

     /*
         Tests to validate the values
         Puts some strings in $error_message if not valide
     */

     if (strlen($error_message) > 0) {
         died($error_message);
         // If there is an error, call the function that displays the message and stops everything
     }

     // Send email
}
```

**What I suggest:**

The best is to have both HTML and PHP in the same page (as if it was in the same file). Use [include()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) at the beginning of `index.php`:

```
<?php
    include('contact.php');
?>

<!-- HTML stuff before -->

<?php
    if (strlen($error_message) > 0) {
        // Now we can display our error message here, with the HTML.
        echo '<div class="error">There was an error: '.$error_message.'</div>';
    }
?>

<form class="form" name="contactform" action="index.php" method="post">
    <!-- See the "action" value has changed, as we won't go to a new "contact" page but stay here -->
</form>

<!-- HTML stuff after -->
```

Then `contact.php` file has to be updated a bit.

```
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
// Notice here that the code won't be executed if the form has not been submitted: so it is not a problem to include the code before the HTML.

     // We don't used the died() function anymore: delete it.

     /*
         That does not change:
         Tests to validate the values
         Puts some strings in $error_message if not valide
     */

     if (strlen($error_message) == 0) {
         // Send the mail only if there is no error.

         // Send email
     }
}
```

Of course this is not the perfect contact page (I won't have stored the errors in a simpled `$error_message` string for example), but this is a good start to begin with PHP and HTML and understand how it works. I encourage you to update and adapt this code once you understood the process.

*Edit: I saw your comment about the modal. This code won't open the modal when the page is reloaded, you'll still have to click the button.
If `strlen($error_message) > 0`, you have to force your modal's CSS style to show it (`style="display:block"` where needed).
Or open it with JS (I assume you have a function `.modal()` or `.open()` somewhere to force it to open.). *(Not my favourite solution as if it is a bit slow to load, the user will see the page without the modal before it opens.)*

Comment: Thank's a lot for your time and explanation. This solution is working but there are few thing that doesn't suit in my page. 1. It is problem that can't open the modal or if it opened it will be after the user see the page ( as you mentioned ). 2. It is break a little bit my css style ( I don't know why ). I guess I will make it with [Javascript](http://www.javascript-coder.com/html-form/javascript-form-validation.phtml) for now.

Comment: I will accept your answer since is working and is helpful. Thank you very much.

Comment: For the modal, you have to look what style you have to put on which `div` so that it stays visible. Or use JS to open it (easier to do with bootstrap's modals, but not so good for user's experience I think). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11868599/how-to-get-twitter-bootstrap-modals-to-stay-open-on-form-submit