# Bootstrap Multiple Modals

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I have an application that can add multiple contacts to a company. Contacts are added via a bootstrap popup modal. My client wants a button "Save and New" to automatically display the popup again after the current contact has been saved. Does anyone have an idea how to do this. I have googled but cannot find anything.

Comment: found this through google, it may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11868599/how-to-get-twitter-bootstrap-modals-to-stay-open-on-form-submit

Answer (score 0):

There are likely several ways to approach this.  It might be helpful to know what the "Save" form does now.  Does it actually submit, thus do a post back to the page and then save the contact data to the database?  Or, do you have an ajax post tied to the button that saves the data and then closes the modal?

I am going to assume that if the user clicks the "Save and New" button, it will do a post.  As such, your functionality would look something like this:

```
$("#saveAndNew").on("click", function() {

    $.post("saveContact.php",
        {
            firstName: $("#contactFirstName").val(),
            lastName: $("#contactLasttName").val(),
            phoneNumber: $("#contactPhone").val()
        },
        function (data, status) {

            if (status == "success") {
                // if the post saves the data without a problem
                $("#contactModal").modal("hide");
                $("#contactForm")[0].reset();
                $("#contactModal").modal("show");
                $("#contactMessage").html("Contact saved!  Ready for a new contact.");

            } else {
              // tell the user there was a problem with their search
              $("#contactMessage").html("Unable to save contact to database.");
            }
     });

});
```

Hope this helps.